# CSS Flex and transformed text

Tags: css

I am trying to get this kind of effect to display a date

[image]

I am using flex and text transform, but am struggling to get it right. I cannot get rid of the extra width to the right of the year.

This is my current result.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.event {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.date {
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  background-color: #f6f5f0;
  color: #d8d6c8;
  padding: 5px;
}

.date .dayAndMonth {
  display: inline-block;
}

.date .month {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.date .day {
  text-align: center
}

.date .year {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
}

.event_details {}
```

```html
<article class="event">
  <div class="date">
    <div class="dayAndMonth">
      <div class="month">Feb</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
    </div>
    <div class="year">2022</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_details">
    <div class="title">Event Title</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use writing-mode: vertical-lr; for more [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
.event {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.date {
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  background-color: #f6f5f0;
  color: #d8d6c8;
  padding: 5px;
  /*Added css*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.date .dayAndMonth {
  display: inline-block;
}

.date .month {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.date .day {
  text-align: center;
}

.date .year {
  display: inline-block;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr; // use this css
  position: relative;
}

.event_details {}
```

```html
<article class="event">
  <div class="date">
    <div class="dayAndMonth">
      <div class="month">Feb</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
    </div>
    <div class="year">2022</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_details">
    <div class="title">Event Title</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This works except the year is going from top to bottom. Changing writing-mode to vertical-rl didn't make a difference. Add a rotation though ( transform: rotate(-180deg);) got it exactly as I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Welcome @StripyTiger

Answer (score 1):

It's because of position relative that anchors `.year` in the `.date` container. It will still take space there as it is relative to that position making the container adjust it's dimension to accommodate the `.year`. There're two ways that I can think of. First, is fix the dimensions of `.date`: `height` and `width` then reposition the `right` and `top` of the `.year`. Or you could just use `position: absolute;` on `.year`, just set the parent container's `width: 50;` and adjust the top property to reposition. See the snippet below:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.event {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.date {
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  background-color: #f6f5f0;
  color: #d8d6c8;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
}

.date .dayAndMonth {
  display: inline-block;
}

.date .month {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.date .day {
  text-align: center
}

.date .year {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
}

.event_details {}
```

```html
<article class="event">
  <div class="date">
    <div class="dayAndMonth">
      <div class="month">Feb</div>
      <div class="day">04</div>
    </div>
    <div class="year">2022</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_details">
    <div class="title">Event Title</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

More on `position`s [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Add a value for `width` to `.year` in your CSS. That is

```css
.date .year {
  /* ... (other styles) */
  width: 20px; /* newly added value for width */
}
```

#### Explanation

On rendering your HTML/CSS code, the browser kind of calculates the widths of elements. At this point, the width of the `.year` div (containing 2022) has been set. After the rotation is rendered, the width was still retained hence the extra space at the right.

So explicitly setting the width removes the extra space to the right of the vertical 2022.

#### Note

You may want to set the font sizes of `.month`, `.day`, and `.year` to be sure that their values are not distorted or superimposed on each other when your page is rendered in a browser where the user has scaled up font sizes.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me. I can't put an image in a comment, but the 2022 appeared in a straight horizontal line (rotated) and escaped out of the shaded box and onto the Event Title

Comment: Are you sure you used this with exactly the combination of code/styles you originally posted? If no, please try again and check. Because you might have changed some parts of your original code before adding this proposed change in width.